# google endpoint use Explorer with a local HTTP API

Tags: android, api, https, google-cloud-endpoints

I want to see my API generated with Google Endpoint locally.

If I run the "Hello world" backend example generated by Android studio and I connect to `localhost:8080` and I click on the third link, the browser opens the page where I can test my API.

There I have an error about connection on HTTPS:

```
The API you are exploring is hosted over HTTP, which can cause problems. Learn how to use Explorer with a local HTTP API.
```

If I click on "Learn how to..." I'm redirect to this page:
https://developers.google.com/explorer-help/#hitting_local_api

If the proposed solution proposed is right, my question is how to open Chrome with these special flags on Windows 10?

I also try to click on the shield in the navigation bar but with no result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the right instructions!

Go to, for example:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application
```

and execute:

```
chrome.exe --user-data-dir=test --unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure=http://localhost:8080
```

It will start a Chrome session in which you can test your API.

Answer (score 10):

I found a simple solution

**1.**  I was having similar problem as shown below

[image]

**2.** solution is to click on the small icon inside at address bar as shown below

[image]

**3.**  then click on load unsafe scripts , that's it now API explorer will work :D

[image]

Answer (score 7):

I found that when the page loads with that error, it can easily be corrected by right clicking the *shieldshape* in extreme right of chrome searchbar and then click *loading of the script*